# How to know current playing text in animated_text_kit package?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying figure it out
but I have no idea

here is my code , almost same example code

```
SizedBox(
  width: 250.0,
  child: TypewriterAnimatedTextKit(
    onTap: () {},
    text: ['aaaaa','bbbbb','ccccc','ddddd'],
    textStyle: TextStyle(
      color: kBlueGray,
      fontSize: 20.sp,
    ),
    speed: Duration(milliseconds: 550),
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
  ),
),
```

text list is actually keyword for searching.
so i wanna make user to search without textfield input.

Comment: I missed it and now I just made it
Thanks Dude 

Answer (score 0):

HERE'S MY ANSWER

```
List<String> animatedTextList = ["Iron man", "Superman", "Joker", "Hulk", "Dude"];
String currentAnimatedText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    currentAnimatedText = animatedTextList[0];
    super.initState();
  }

**********

SizedBox(
    width: 0.60.sw,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.h),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 250.0,
        child: TypewriterAnimatedTextKit(
          onNext: (value, value2) {
            currentAnimatedText =
                animatedTextList[value + 1];
            print(currentAnimatedText);
          },
          onTap: () {
            print(currentAnimatedText);
          },
          text: animatedTextList,
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            color: kBlueGray,
            fontSize: 20.sp,
          ),
          speed: Duration(milliseconds: 550),
          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    ),
```